# Navigating a formula as a directed tree to find all occurence of a symbol

Tags: r, tree, formula

In R, a formula can be seen as a tree where the parent node is located on index `[[1]]` and the left and right terms in subsequent indices.

For example, with the formula `f` defined as:

```
f <- y ~ (a*x) +(b*x) + (c*z)
```

`f[[1]]` is `~` and `f[[2]]` is `y`. The last term `f[[3]]` will return the right-hand side of the equation. `f[[3]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]]` finally returns the first occurence of `x`.

Seen that way, the equation is a tree data structure similar to this:
[image]

How could I navigate through the tree to get all the paths that lead to a certain symbols?

For example to get to `x`, there are two paths, {3, 2, 2, 2, 3} and {3, 2, 3, 2, 3}. We can check with `f[[3]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]]` that we indeed get the first occurrence of `x` in the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rrapply::rrapply()` to recursively search for the element and return the indices:

```
library(rrapply)

find_ind <- \(f, value) {
  rrapply(
    f,
    condition = \(x) x == value,
    f = \(x, .xpos) .xpos,
    how = "flatten"
  )
}

find_ind(f, "x")

[[1]]
[1] 3 2 2 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 3 2 3
```

Confirm that these are the indices of `x` in the formula:

```
lapply(find_ind(f, "x"), \(i) f[[i]])

[[1]]
x

[[2]]
x
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using the option `how = "melt"` in `rrapply::rrapply()`. This returns the indices for each level and each leaf in the syntax tree, after which we can simply filter the rows corresponding to `x` values:

```
library(rrapply)

f <- y ~ (a*x) +(b*x) + (c*z)

rrapply(f, how = "melt") |>
  subset(value == "x")

#>    L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 value
#> 8   3  2  2  2  3     x
#> 12  3  2  3  2  3     x
```

Or even shorter, using the `condition` argument in `rrapply::rrapply()`:

```
rrapply(f, condition = \(x) x == "x", how = "melt")
#>   L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 value
#> 1  3  2  2  2  3     x
#> 2  3  2  3  2  3     x
```

Comment: The second solution is super cool! However, it returns the indices as characters instead of numeric. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Not really (the indices correspond to the node names, which is why they are characters). You'll have to convert the characters to integers afterwards, e.g. `rrapply(f, condition = \(x) x == "x", how = "melt") |> type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`. Or use the solution of @Richie Sacramento.